# Why process.env.username readys the computer hostname (in Windows 10), instead of the key-value pair defined in config.env file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dotenv

I defined username and password in `config.env` file and tried to retrieve with dotenv package.

When I try to retrieve `username`, it gets the hostname. Regardless if I define all lowercase letters or uppercase letters; it returns the computer hostname.

Is it with the `process.env.username` having some variable name collision, and by design it would read the hostname for `process.env.username`?

Here is snippet code from app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

const dotenv = require('dotenv')

// Setting up the post for server
dotenv.config({
    path: './utils/config.env',
    override: true
})

console.log(`*** Username: ${process.env.USERNAME}`)
console.log(`*** Username: ${process.env.USER_NAME}`)
console.log(`*** Username: ${process.env.UNAME}`)
console.log(`*** Password: ${process.env.password}`)

const PORT = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server has started on port: ${process.env.PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode.`)
})
```

Here is what is inside *config.env* file:

```
PORT = 3000
NODE_ENV = development

USERNAME = USERNAME1
USER_NAME = USERNAME2
UNAME = USERNAME3
password = password@123
```

How should I understand this and (I guess) what is the recommended way of defining username and password in `config.env` file when we deal with NodeJS?

When I added '_' (like USER_NAME, or any other form of 'username'); then it works as expected.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you're using.

Comment: @Phil: I added the node, please check. Thank you for your prompt response!

Comment: What's in your `config.env` file? Please provide samples of what you expect vs what you actually receive. Also, why are you calling `dotenv.config()` multiple times?

Comment: @Phil: Added the snippets for both app.js and config.env. Please take a look. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dotenv by default will not overwrite existing shell variables.

You can configure dotenv with the [override option](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#override) to work around this.

```js
require('dotenv').config({
  path: './utils/config.env',
  override: true,
});
```

This will ignore any existing environment variables with the same names as those in your `config.env` file.

Comment: Your above answer resolved my issue. It was very concise and to the point!! Thank you :)